# How to create a n-dimensional array (or matrix) from braced-init-list using template class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class mat {
private:
    T ptr[N];
public:
    mat() = default;

    template <typename... Args>
    mat(Args&&... args) : ptr{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

    void print(){
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            std::cout << (ptr+i) << ' ' << *(ptr+i) <<'\t';
        }
    }
    
    T operator[](int j){
        return *(ptr+j-1);
    }
};
// deduction guide
template<typename... Args> mat(Args&&...) -> mat<typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type,sizeof...(Args)>;

// need to do -> multi dimensional array;
int main()
{
    mat a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    a.print();
}
```

I want to create an arbitrary n-dimensional array (like say MATLAB) simply by defining something like this:`mat a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};`. How do I do this?

Comment: If you're willing to give up constant dimensions, this will be much easier. BTW `*(ptr+j-1)` is really bad.

Comment: You just have to explicitly indicate what template type to use. The same way you would write `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> arr2D;`

Comment: `auto a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};` should result in `mat<mat<int,3>,2>` ? Or do you want  `mat` to contain a multidimensional `std::array`?

Comment: it is unclear what you expect from `tuple`, is this an attempt to get the multidimensions?

Comment: the tuple is to get the data type of the braced-init-list...ptr will be defined as int if we have mat a = {1, 2, 3} and as double if mat a = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}

Comment: deduction guides are a C++17 feature

Comment: You seem to expect `mat a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};` to deduce `a` as `mat<mat<int, 3>, 2>`. But the compiler is given no indication whatsoever what the inner type should be. It could just as well be `mat<std::array<int, 3>, 2>` or `mat<std::vector<int>, 2>` or `mat<std::tuple<int, int, int>, 2>` or an infinite number of other possibilities.

Comment: Yes exactly, but how do i implement that using template. Thanks in advance.